# Apache-PHP max_execution_time fatal exception handling

Tags: php, oracle, apache, timeout, fatal-error

I have a PHP module that fetches data from an Oracle DB, using the call
    `oci_Execute(statement);`

Now based on the search parameters provided by the user the search can sometimes takes more than 30 minutes. In such cases I want to cancel the search (at PHP level) and notify the user to reconsider the search params.

I attempted that by setting the PHP timeout variable `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` file. I have set up a `ErrorDocument 404` redirect in the apache `httpd.conf` file (and it works fine with not found php pages). However, when the php times out and the oci_execute is still processing, PHP throws a fatal exception and crashes.

I have already tried try/catch and came to know that it doesn't work for fatal errors.
I have tried registering a shutdown function via `register_shutdown_function`, it is never reached after the fatal error.
I have tried setting apache timeout directives but they never take effect in the presence of PHP scripts.

I want either apache or PHP to respond with an error code and redirect to a page saying 'dear user please reconsider your search parameters' :) at the moment I see a fatal exception after timeout generated at oci_Execute line.

Rephrasing the question; how can I get out of the `oci_execute` call without a fatal exception, anything but a fatal exception will work.

Comment: as the default behavior is to raise a fatal error, may be you could start by running a query (a count() on only one column of course to make run this quickly) that counts the number of record for that search and if that goes over 1000 records for example, you warn the user, otherwise you authorize the usesr to run his "big search"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the Oracle database level, you can set a resource limit by altering the Profile.  You should be able to trap the "error" from Oracle when you hit the resource limit.

ALTER PROFILE: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_2008.htm#SQLRF00813

Comment: thanks .. will look into it if I can't find any solution on the PHP side .. as I dont have administrative access to DB ...